# is there any program that can tell me which files have been transferred from my computer thru the web

Tags: virus, file-system

Is there a program that can tell me which files have been transferred from my computer thru the web?

So if I have virus on my computer that transfer files I will know about it according to the files list that have been transferred.

Comment: No,  by the time a virus is running on your machine its probably too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want exactly, you can use an IDS, like [Snort](http://www.snort.org/), to record and alert based on certain criteria. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) can also be used with filters to log file transfers.

Comment: Any file-stealing virus worth it's salt would use an encrypted channel to transfer files.  You could assume, based on the amount of data being uploaded, that a file is being transferred, but will likely be no way to know which file, from the network side.  You could monitor and track file access locally, but if your machine is compromised with a virus, they likely would hide any forensic evidence.

Comment: @DonSimon True, but most malware is lowest-common-denominator, rather than "worth its salt".